# MS Project to Excel Gantt Chart using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-project, gantt-chart, vba

I'm trying to export some tasks from MS Project to Excel using a VBA script in Project. So far I am able to export the data I want with no issue and it opens in Excel just fine. What I'm trying to do now is take that data in Excel and replicate into a Gantt chart similar to the one in Project. I know I know, what's the point of going through all this just to get a Gantt chart in Excel when I already have one in Project right? Well among other things this Excel gantt chart is being made so that everyone without MS Project can view the scheduled tasks without having MS Project.

So what I've tried so far(since excel doesn't have a built in Gantt maker) is to make the chart on the spreadsheet, coloring the cells to mimic a Gantt chart. My two main issues: 
1. I don't know how to add an offset for each specific task depending on what day it starts on
2. I don't know how to color the correct number of cells(right now it colors cells in multiples of 7, or weeks at a time instead of down to the specific day.

```
Sub ExportToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim proj As Project
Dim t As Task
Dim pj As Project
Dim i As Integer
Set pj = ActiveProject
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True
AppActivate "Excel"
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
xlSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Project Name"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = pj.Name
xlSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Project Title"
xlSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = pj.Title
xlSheet.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Task ID"
xlSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value = "Task Name"
xlSheet.Cells(4, 3).Value = "Task Start"
xlSheet.Cells(4, 4).Value = "Task Finish"

For Each t In pj.Tasks
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 1).Value = t.ID
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 2).Value = t.Name
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 3).Value = t.Start
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 4).Value = t.Finish

    Dim x As Integer
    'x is the duration of task in days(i.e. half a day long task is 0.5)
    x = t.Finish - t.Start
    'Loop to add day of week headers and color cells to mimic Gantt chart
    For i = 0 To x
        xlSheet.Cells(4, (7 * i) + 5).Value = "S"
        xlSheet.Cells(4, (7 * i) + 6).Value = "M"
        xlSheet.Cells(4, (7 * i) + 7).Value = "T"
        xlSheet.Cells(4, (7 * i) + 8).Value = "W"
        xlSheet.Cells(4, (7 * i) + 9).Value = "T"
        xlSheet.Cells(4, (7 * i) + 10).Value = "F"
        xlSheet.Cells(4, (7 * i) + 11).Value = "S"

        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, ((7 * i) + 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, (7 * i) + 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, (7 * i) + 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, (7 * i) + 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, (7 * i) + 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, (7 * i) + 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, (7 * i) + 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    Next i
Next t
End Sub
```

[Screenshot of current MS project output in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrDuH.png)

If anyone has any better suggestions please let me know. I'm pretty new to this and not sure if this is even possible or if it is possible and just so complicated that its not even worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, I have a MACRO that does that for years.
Use the piece of code below.

```
Sub ExportToExcel()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim proj As Project
Dim t As Task
Dim pj As Project
Dim pjDuration As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Set pj = ActiveProject
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True
'AppActivate "Excel"
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
xlSheet.cells(1, 1).Value = "Project Name"
xlSheet.cells(1, 2).Value = pj.Name
xlSheet.cells(2, 1).Value = "Project Title"
xlSheet.cells(2, 2).Value = pj.Title
xlSheet.cells(1, 4).Value = "Project Start"
xlSheet.cells(1, 5).Value = pj.ProjectStart
xlSheet.cells(2, 4).Value = "Project Finish"
xlSheet.cells(2, 5).Value = pj.ProjectFinish

xlSheet.cells(1, 7).Value = "Project Duration"
pjDuration = pj.ProjectFinish - pj.ProjectStart
xlSheet.cells(1, 8).Value = pjDuration & "d"

xlSheet.cells(4, 1).Value = "Task ID"
xlSheet.cells(4, 2).Value = "Task Name"
xlSheet.cells(4, 3).Value = "Task Start"
xlSheet.cells(4, 4).Value = "Task Finish"

' Add day of the week headers for the entire Project's duration
For i = 0 To pjDuration
    xlSheet.cells(4, i + 5).Value = pj.ProjectStart + i
    xlSheet.cells(4, i + 5).NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"
Next

For Each t In pj.Tasks
    xlSheet.cells(t.ID + 4, 1).Value = t.ID
    xlSheet.cells(t.ID + 4, 2).Value = t.Name
    xlSheet.cells(t.ID + 4, 3).Value = t.Start
    xlSheet.cells(t.ID + 4, 3).NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"
    xlSheet.cells(t.ID + 4, 4).Value = t.Finish
    xlSheet.cells(t.ID + 4, 4).NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"

    For i = 5 To pjDuration + 5
        'Loop to add day of week headers and color cells to mimic Gantt chart
        If t.Start <= xlSheet.cells(4, i) And t.Finish >= xlSheet.cells(4, i) Then
            xlSheet.cells(t.ID + 4, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        End If
     Next i
Next t
```

Comment: Wow awesome!!! This works out a lot better than what I was trying to do, just have to tweak a few things but this is looking good so far! Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi - I'm new to Project Macros so I thought I would start with your code how ever when running it in Project 2013 I get a "Complie error: User-defined type not defined" on the Dim xlApp As Excel.Application command. Reading up ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680402/excel-vba-compile-throws-a-user-defined-type-not-defined-error-but-does-not-go ) there seems to have been changes to the format of the code. Is this correct or do I need to look else where on my own Project set up as I would have thought the code backwards compatible ? Thanks in advance T

Comment: @TerranBrown can you open a new post with your question, tag my name with the `@` so I'll see it

Comment: Hi Shai - I tried tagging you via @ but for some reason failed... I've opened the new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913058/ms-project-to-excel-gantt-chart-using-vba-follow-on - thanks for your help in advance