# "User-defined type not defined" error with button only, no code errors

Tags: vba, excel, form-control

**Issue:**
When I click a macro assigned button in my workbook the following error appeared:

> "User-defined type not defined"

The error box appears, however, it did not highlight any code that may have produced the error. When I ran the macro from the compiler, the code executed without error. I was able to figure out that when I inserted a new button and assigned the same macro to the new button, the code executed without error.

Facts about the workbook:

- The workbook includes multiple macros and multiple sheets as well as buttons linked to most of the macros (6 buttons)
- The workbook is saved daily with a new date as modifications are made. The same button in previous workbooks do not produce this error.
- There was an issue with one button a month ago and it was replaced, now a different button has this same issue. I would like to avoid replacing buttons every time this error occurs as I am not the end user.
- This workbook was originally created in Excel 2010 but I have been using it in Excel 2013, though I made the switch months before this issue (not sure if info is relevant).

I saw a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680402/excel-vba-compile-throws-a-user-defined-type-not-defined-error-but-does-not-go), however the issue for me is not in my code, only in the form control. I would just like to know if anyone has seen this before and if there is a way to avoid needing to replace the buttons every time they "go bad."

Comment: So if you run the `..._Click()` you don't get an error but when you click the button it does? Is the VBA project modified as well or just the sheet contents?

Comment: There must be a macro attached to that button which is causing the error to pop-up. Essentially, you need to debug this macro. If no particular line is highlighted then I (personally) like to take this approach: `comment` **all** lines in the macro and then test the button. Now it should work without a problem. Then start to `uncomment` a few lines and press the button again. Repeat and slowly `uncomment` all lines of code until you have found your culprit. Then post the code here and let us know what kind of VBA code can cause such errors. I'd like to know!

Comment: Open the Visual Basic Editor and select Debug->Compile VBAProject from the menu.  It should jump you to the line with the error.

Comment: The macro code itself runs without issue. I have selected Compile VBAProject like @Comintern suggested and still, no error nor does it jump to any lines. I have even stepped through the code line by line, again without any error.

Comment: @Ralph I can post the code, but I'm not getting an error with it, it's literally only the button. I even tried deleting all the code from the sub and the button still returned "User-defined type not defined" !

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Yes, the VBA project is modified as well. It's only when the button is clicked. To clarify, I do not have a button_Click() procedure, I just Right click + assign macro to a button on the worksheet.

Comment: Do you have any add-ins installed? It sounds like there is an early bound reference somewhere that is missing.

Comment: @Comintern I do have add-ins installed. I'm not sure what you mean by an early bound reference if you could elaborate.

Comment: It's a type from a reference. For example `Dim foo As FileSystemObject` is early bound - `Dim foo As Object` is late bound.  If the reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime is missing, the compiler can't find anything that lets it know what a `FileSystemObject` *is*, so it throws your error.

Comment: Here is the practical approach to what @Comintern is saying: disable all add-ins and possibly also disable (if there is one) `Personal.XLSB`. Then see if you still get this error. If not, then he is right with his assumption. Start to re-enable one add-in at a time and see when you get the error again. Then check with the developer of that add-in what's causing the problem.

Comment: Either what @Ralph suggests, or work the other way - trace the code through your button handlers to see if they are calling any functions from your add-in. If the add-ins are .xlam files and you have access to the code, you could also try Debug->Compile on them individually.  Each project compiles separately, and they can compile on demand when called from other code.

Comment: Once you have resolved the issue it would be great if you could share your findings (in case anybody else has a similar problem).